# mongoose: can't get new pushed data into array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to push a new array in MongoDB using Mongoose. It works fine and the new data are pushed to the database, but I want to get back the new created object from the query, but even using {new: true} it does not work.

Schema example:

```
BusinessSchema { CustomersSchema { BonusArray }}
```

The query I'm using is:

```
            businessData.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': uid, 'customers._id': customer }, { $push: {'customers.$.bonus': bonusData}}, { 'new': true})
            .then( (result) => {
                console.log(result) //Expecting to get the new bonusData pushed with this query
                cb()
            })
            .catch( err => { 
                console.log(err)
                cb({ status: 200, success: false, message: err.message}, null); 
            })
```

The new data are pushed to the DB, but it returns al the DB Schema.
I tried using `{returnOriginal: false}` instead of new:true but it does not work.

What I'm missing? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need a newer Mongoose version? Try updating.

Comment: is your data is updating.?

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari Yes, the data is updated in Mongo.

Comment: @ParthShah I updated to the latest version but still not working.

Comment: @proquibas use findByIdAndUpdate and check

Answer (score 0):

replace { 'new': true} by { new: true} maybe it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this workaround:

```
                businessData.findById({ '_id': uid,}, 'customers', { 'new': true})
                .then( (result) => {
                     let index = result.customers.findIndex(x=>x._id == customer)
                     result.customers[index].bonus.push(bonusData)
                     newBonus = result.customers[index].bonus[result.customers[index].bonus.length-1]
                     result.markModified('customers')
                     result.save()
                     .then((result) => console.log("Result OK"))
                     .catch((error) => cb({ status: 200, success: false, message: err.message}, null))
                     cb()
                 })
                 .catch( err => { 
                     cb({ status: 200, success: false, message: err.message}, null); 
                 })
```